# Running Selenium Python Script as a Windows Service , but browser not showing up

Tags: python, selenium, windows-services

So I have managed to convert my python script as a windows service and have also ticked that allow it to interact with the local desktop. But still on running the service , I do not see any browser pop up . The service is running perfectly though in the background - logs are being logged in the file. I really need to display for my application needs . Any ideas or any workarounds for this ?
Thanks ! Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code for reference :

```
class AutomatoSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Automato-Job-Service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Automato Whatsapp Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.stop_requested = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)
        logging.info('Stopping service ...')
        stop_consume()
        self.stop_requested = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_,'')
        )
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        logging.info(' ** Starting Whatsapp Job service ** ')
        # Simulate a main loop
        run_consume()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AutomatoSvc)
```

Comment: By nature, windows services run in the background...what are you trying to accomplish by running it as a service?

Comment: Actually I want to hide the console output and show only the display . Also I'd like to stop and run this script as I wish